# Nextjs: custom error page with correct status code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I followed the next [docs regarding a custom error page](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page). I want to reuse the error page if certain errors occur at `getStaticProps`. Something like:

```
const Page: NextPage<Props> = ({ pageData, error }: Props) => {
  if (error) return <Error statusCode={500} />;
  return <Page data={pageData} />;
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({
  params,
}: {
  params: { [prop: string]: string[] };
}) => {
  const { slug } = params;
  const {pageData, error} = getPageData(slug)

  return {
    props: {
      pageData: page || null,
      error: error || null,
    },
  };
};

export default Page;
```

The error page is just like in the docs:

```
function Error({ statusCode }) {
  return (
    <p>
      {statusCode ? `An error ${statusCode} occurred on server` : 'An error occurred on client'}
    </p>
  );
}

Error.getInitialProps = ({ res, err }) => {
  const statusCode = res ? res.statusCode : err ? err.statusCode : 404;
  return { statusCode };
};

export default Error;
```

This works but the status code ist wrong. Nextjs still answers a request to this page with a status code 200. I need it to set the status code to 500 as if there was a server error.

[image]

Comment: Can you do a hard reload of that route with params and confirm ? That looks like an error on a client side redirect - see _An error occured on client_

Comment: I don't think it's possible to force a 500 status code return in `getStaticProps`, but you could return a 404 page by returning `{ notFound: true }` as described in [How to redirect to 404 page if data is invalid in getStaticProps?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68447009/1870780).

Answer (score -1):

you can change your page status code if you are using "getServerSideProps" or "getStaticProps", you only need to change the response status code before returning the page props:

```
const HomePage = ({pageProps}) => {

 if (pageProps.hasError) {
     return <CustomError status={error.status} message={error.message}/>
 }

 return <div>This is home page </div>

 }

 export const getServerSideProps = async ({req,res}) => {

 try {
     const homeData = await fetchHomeData()

     return {
         props: {
             data: homeData
         }
     }

 } catch (err) {

     res.statusCode = exception.response.status  /* this is the key part */

     return {
         props: {
             hasError: true, error: {
                 status: exception.response.status || 500,
                 message: exception.message
             }
         }
     }
 }
}
```