# Nextjs routing to username slug url e.g (site.com/username)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js, url-routing

So what I'm trying to achieve is a username page, for example, if a username is **Jack** then **site.com/jack**

My folder structure looks like this **pages > [user] > index.js** but because of this if there's a typo or someone goes to a page that doesn't exist (site.com/abc) the **user** page will be displayed.

This is what my code looks like, obviously, it is throwing an error because this is incomplete. I can't figure out how can I get the username

```
import React from "react";


export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { user } = context.query;
return {
props: {
user
}}}


export default function Header() {

  return (
    <div>
      index
    </div>
  )
 }
```

Comment: You can return `{ notFound: true }` from inside `getServerSideProps` if the user is not valid. See [How to redirect to 404 page if data is invalid in getStaticProps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68443858/how-to-redirect-to-404-page-if-data-is-invalid-in-getstaticprops) (question mentions `getStaticProps` but same applies to `getServerSideProps`).

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if there is a user with that specific name, if not you can redirect to the 404 page.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const { user } = context.query;
    if (!user) {
     return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/404',
        permanent: false,
      },
    }
  return {
    props: {user}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
  }

}
```